# SPRING MVC + Hibernate, cannot get all records

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc

Im trying to create Webbapp using SpringMVC, Hibernate and Tomcat.
Im a complete newbie so pleas do not get angry.

So I have created the DB, got access to it, can create tables etc.

Index page shows normally, but when im trying to list all records from table I got error:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'contractsRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'pl.Bluesoft.repositories.ContractsRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'pl.Bluesoft.repositories.ContractsRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:676)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:642)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:558)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:499)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:172)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2555)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2544)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Below my classess and xmls:

**Contract Entity**

```
package pl.Bluesoft.entities;


import pl.Bluesoft.entities.System;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Contract {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long Id;
private int contractNumber;
private double contractAmount;
private java.util.Date contractStartDate;
private java.util.Date contractEndDate;
@OneToOne
private System system;
private boolean isContractActive;
private String contractAmountPeriod;


public long getId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    Id = id;
}

public int getContractNumber() {
    return contractNumber;
}

public void setContractNumber(int contractNumber) {
    this.contractNumber = contractNumber;
}

public double getContractAmount() {
    return contractAmount;
}

public void setContractAmount(double contractAmount) {
    this.contractAmount = contractAmount;
}

public java.util.Date getContractStartDate() {
    return contractStartDate;
}

public void setContractStartDate(java.util.Date contractStartDate) {
    this.contractStartDate = contractStartDate;
}

public java.util.Date getContractEndDate() {
    return contractEndDate;
}

public void setContractEndDate(java.util.Date contractEndDate) {
    this.contractEndDate = contractEndDate;
}

public System getSystem() {
    return system;
}

public void setSystem(System system) {
    this.system = system;
}

public boolean isContractActive() {
    return isContractActive;
}

public void setContractActive(boolean contractActive) {
    isContractActive = contractActive;
}

public String getContractAmountPeriod() {
    return contractAmountPeriod;
}

public void setContractAmountPeriod(String contractAmountPeriod) {
    this.contractAmountPeriod = contractAmountPeriod;
}
}
```

Contracts Repository:

```
 package pl.Bluesoft.repositories;

    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import pl.Bluesoft.entities.Contract;

    @Repository
    public interface ContractsRepository extends CrudRepository <Contract, Long> 
         {

      }
```

Main Controller:

```
package pl.Bluesoft.controllers;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import pl.Bluesoft.entities.Contract;
    import pl.Bluesoft.repositories.ContractsRepository;

    @Controller
    public class MainController {


    @Autowired
    private ContractsRepository contractsRepository;



    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showIndex(){
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Contract> getAllContracts() {
        return contractsRepository.findAll();
    }


          }
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

<display-name>ContractViewer</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name/>
        <param-value/>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name/>
        <param-value/>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/appContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.Bluesoft" />


    <mvc:annotation-driven/>


</beans>
```

persistence xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="myDatabase" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/BazaUmow" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

The repository isn't instantiated. Add to your application context:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="pl.Bluesoft.repositories" />
```

in order to scan the packages of your classpath containig repositories. [See also reference docu](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods).